# Help identifying this weed/plant?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

We are new to this house and to gardening so don't always know if something is a plant or a weed. These plants are growing among some lavender plants, and in the brick paving next to the beds. Can you help me identify what these are and what is the best way to get rid of them?

[image: Weeds in lavender flower bed]

Location: Netherlands

What I tried: scrolled through a google image search of weeds ('onkruiden' in Dutch), but nothing seems to match these.

Comment: I believe this is Aegopodium. If identified as such, see this post: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11091/what-is-this-weed-and-how-can-i-eliminate-it

Comment: yep, ground elder (Aegopodium).

Comment: @Brenn Thank you for identifying the plant! I must say it's rather disappointing to learn that the weed is so hard to get rid of. We have quite a lot of it unfortunately :-(

Comment: But Aegopodium is also a nice vegetable. When you treat it as useful plant (and not as weed) it will vanish.